# FileSystemWatcher OnChanged event not updating the web page UI

Tags: c#, asp.net

Onchanged event not updating the web page UI.

Program control flows into OnChanged event and updates the values of UI components but it is not getting reflected on the webpage.

```
public void FileWatcher()
        {
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = xmldirectory;
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            watcher.Filter = "*.xml";
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            txtStatus.Text ="Changed";
            btnCheck.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Comment: Could you include your code so we can suggest what the issue may be?  My blind guess: the OnChanged event happens on the server side, you're looking at the page in a browser; there's no connection between the two / refresh code in play, so the page you load will never update unless manually refreshed.

Comment: @JohnLBevan I have included the code. How to refresh the page with updated UI components.

Comment: You could write some javascript to poll your server asking if there's any new info; e.g.: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/displaying-real-time-data-using-html5-and-asp.net.htm

Comment: Or you could open a connection between client & server so they can talk on an ad-hoc basis (e.g. using SignalR): http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc

Comment: Or you could simply refresh the whole page every few seconds; e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp

Comment: SignalR is the most sophisticated, http-equiv the least - however read the overview of each and decide which is most appropriate for your use case.